# How to accept requests and execute them in different threads?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a `RequestHandler` class which will be instantiated and passed to all the clients and the clients will send requests to it via `handle_new_request` method. The `RequestHandler` should also independently be able to execute these requests.
The request below looks quite ordinary, but in the application to serve the request might take time hence I want to execute the requests asynchronously.

```
from collections import deque
import time
class Request:
    """
    Naive implementation of a request class.
    """
    def __init__(self, req_name: str):
        self.req_name = req_name


class RequestsHandler:
    """
    Implementation for a naive requests handler class that accepts
    requests from clients and serves them via a ThreadPool.
    """
    def __init__(self, max_working_threads:int = 5):
        self.max_working_threads = max_working_threads
        self.request_queue = deque()
    def handle_new_request(self, new_req: Request):
        """
        Puts the new request made by a client into the request_queue.
        :param new_req: Request made.
        :return: None
        """
        self.request_queue.append(new_req)
    def serve_request(self):
        """
        Pops a new request from the request queue and serves it.
        :return: None
        """
        new_request: Request = self.request_queue.popleft()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('served request %s'%new_request.req_name)
```

`handle_new_request` and `serve_request` methods of the class `RequestHandler` should work asynchronously, and the object should
be alive even while the queue is empty.